# Rerturn returning ID from function

Tags: postgresql, return

I'm basically trying to return the updated id from the following function. The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION confirmUser(_token varchar(255)) RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
   return (UPDATE users SET isConfirmed = true where _token = token RETURNING id));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can return the value like that. You need to store it into a variable and then return that variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION confirmUser(_token varchar(255)) RETURNS integer 
AS 
$$
declare
   _id integer;
BEGIN
   UPDATE users SET isConfirmed = true where _token = token 
   RETURNING id
   into _id;

   return _id;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But you don't need a PL/pgSQL function for this. A plain SQL function will do just as well:

```
CREATE FUNCTION confirmUser(_token varchar(255)) RETURNS integer 
AS 
$$
   UPDATE users SET isConfirmed = true where _token = token 
   RETURNING id
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

But you have to make sure that `token` is unique, otherwise this will fail.

Comment: Yes, I make sure token is unique. The given code in the question was simplified.

Comment: @celebisait: also see my update, you don't need a PL/pgSQL function. Using a plain SQL function makes things a lot easier